# AngularJS ui-router - view disappears on reload

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

Recently I started to use `ui-router` to manage my page status.

I noticed that when I run the server for the first time, the content is there but if I navigate through the pages or reload the page the contents disappears.

I'm aware there was a bug on `ui-router` that could be causing this. I updated `ui-router` however the error still persists.

Did anyone manage to find a fix or work around it?

Edit ----

My investigation has lead me to believe that it has nothing to do with the ui-router and more on the time the app takes to complete the promise. As I will get Violation warnings on the setTimeout as part of jQuery

Comment: UI router works fine. Please post your code

Comment: You can find the repo in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was partially right on my last edit hence this answer; jQuery had something to do with my problem (through the use of promises to retrieve data), however it had also to do with how the ui-router works:

As the page content is loaded, ui-router will manage the first load (and subsequent reloads) with the data that is provided by the GET request.

As this is a promise it is not guaranteed (especially as you grow your DB) that the data will be there in time to render the page.

To avoid from happening use the resolve property as part of ngRoute. This property allows for all the necessary data to be loaded before rendering the DOM.

If you want to read more about follow the link below:

https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c

My code below:

App.js

```
'use strict';


 angular
    .module('knoweeApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url:'/',
                templateUrl: 'views/user.html',
                controller: 'UserCtrl as user',
                resolve: {
                    user: function(userFinder) {
                        return userFinder.getUsers();
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('teacher', {
                url:'/teacher/:name',
                templateUrl: 'views/teacher.html',
                controller: 'TeacherCtrl as teacher'

            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    }]);
```

Service: userFinder

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name knoweeApp.userFinder
 * @description
 * # userFinder
 * Service in the knoweeApp.
 */
angular.module('knoweeApp')
  .service('userFinder', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function

    this.getUsers = function (){
        return $.get('users.json');
    };

  });
```

Controller: UserCtrl

```
'use strict';

angular.module('knoweeApp')
    .controller('UserCtrl', function (userFinder,user) {

    this.teachers = user;

    this.increment = function (item) {
        item.rating += 1;
    };

    this.decrement = function (item) {
        item.rating -= 1;
    };

});
```

Hope this helps, contact me if in doubt